# Simple DataGrid Binding to Remote SQL Server 2005/8 Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, data-binding

How can we Use a DataGrid in WPF to show/update/add/delete records in a Table? I have watched/read and tried many tutorials, but I can't find a single, easy to understand tutorial on how to bind data with a remote database.

I can't seem to find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use Linq2Sql (less difficult to learn than EntityFramework) try a tutorial like this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGrid.aspx

or
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

And you will do fine.

Comment: Thanks for the links - How come all the samples online for WPF Databinding seem to only connect to a local Northwind database? How can I make it connect to a remote DB on a server somewhere? Am I missing something completely obvious here?

Comment: In asp.net all you need to connect to a remote DB is a different connectionstring. It really does not make that much of a difference. I guess in WPF it is the same (I am more a web developer) Of course, your SQL server has to accept remote connections, your firewall settings need to be ok but apart from the infrastructural aspects the programming is pretty much identical

Comment: Ohh okay, so it's *pretty* much the same as WinForms, but in WPF you just pass the result of the query from the remote db query to the datasource or something? Instead of from the northwind? Sorry if this seems really dumb - I just find WPF really confusing for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried to complete step one from the first link, setup a add a new item (LINQ-to-SQL Class) but not from northwind but from your remote DB? Because if that works, the rest is easy...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to choose a data access technique to retrieve the records from the DB to create data that you can bind to.

The most modern approach is to use the EntityFramework - excellent concept - It will save you a lot of development time in the long-run but has a huge learning curve.

Not wanting to tackle that, you can use DataSets by connecting to a datasource from the Server Explorer of visual studio, right clicking on the tables that you link and creating a data-bound grid on your WPF page.

Either way, there is more learning to do but hopefully you have more of an idea where to start learning.